# Merging multiple Extent reports to single report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, extent

I have a maven multi module project, I am able to generate the Extent HTML report for each individual module.How to merge and attach the individual reports into single report.

Version :
Extent Reports : 2.41.2

Comment: Version 2 reached end of life a long time ago.  Version 4 is in development so you should plan to upgrade soon. The API is not expected to change from version 3 but everything else will.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same location and file name for the file and initialize it like this:

```
extentReportFile = some-path-that-you-use-in-all-modules;
ExtentReports extentReports = new ExtentReports(extentReportFile, false);
```

it should store all the reports into one single .html file.

You can create a ExtentReports factory in your core module - the one that all the other modules can see into - and implement the code in your modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Klov. demo [here](http://klov.herokuapp.com/user/signon)
In a nice looking dashboard you have all tests as builds and general info's about them. What I like the most is that once a TC's is executed will be automatically updated in the dashboard - so you can check the results in real time no need to wait for full report.
It is simple to be implemented, you can check [here](http://extentreports.com/docs/klov/).

Some issues are present also :(

- Screenshots are not displayed correctly
- Category and description are not displayed

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar requirement. I achieved it. (Extent Report V3 and above)

BaseTest is being extended by all the test class.

Class BaseTest{

```
        public static ExtentReports extent =new ExtentReports();//initiating here is very important
        public static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;

@BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuiteSetup() {
        String filepath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(filepath+"/Report.html");     
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
    }

@AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public void afterSuite() {
        extent.flush();
    }

}
```